# Failing to produce to kafka brokers java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am able to produce messages from the kafka-console-producer.sh but the java client is failing to produce with the exception mentioned below.

Using java 7, Kafka version is 0.8.2.1

Exception seen

```
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:498)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getLong(HeapByteBuffer.java:406)
at kafka.api.ProducerResponse$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ProducerResponse.scala:40)
at kafka.api.ProducerResponse$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ProducerResponse.scala:36)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at kafka.api.ProducerResponse$$anonfun$1.apply(ProducerResponse.scala:36)
at kafka.api.ProducerResponse$$anonfun$1.apply(ProducerResponse.scala:33)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at kafka.api.ProducerResponse$.readFrom(ProducerResponse.scala:33)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:114)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:275)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:113)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:105)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:105)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:78)
at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:35)
at com.myapplication.kafka.KafkaProducer.write(KafkaProducer.java:40)
```

Any pointers on how to debug ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the kafka client to produce messages was using 0.10 jar and the kafka cluster was 0.8.2.1

Adding the proper kafka dependency 0.8.2.1 solved the issue.